# Highcharts displaying white space for bars when all values are zero

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

when all the values are 0 in the chart and I don't have a max axis value I am getting blank space in place of bars
[image]

Comment: Hi @kishore kingmaker, Could you explain your problem more precisely? It seems that the result is correct.

Comment: @ppotaczek see the 0 lines, it has white space for bars. It should not be shown

Comment: kishore kingmaker - please share your chart configuration object with sample data.

Comment: @ppotaczek https://jsfiddle.net/zwp0c4qd/17/ u can refer this example js fiddle by me

Comment: @ppotaczek https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMPMRp but the same is not coming in codepen lol

Comment: Ok, thanks for the example. You can decrease `threshold` property, which is set to `0` by default, to show the columns: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4t259bwz/

Comment: @ppotaczek, I no need the columns to be shown. It should be like a plain line like the code pen example. Thanks for the try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase `gridZIndex` property for `yAxis`:

```
yAxis: {
    gridZIndex: 4,
    ...
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0e89puxL/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.minPointLength

Comment: it is not fixing the issue

Comment: @kishore kingmaker, so please explain exactly what is the correct result.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMPMRp  this will be the correct result but its showing only in code pen @ppotaczrk

Comment: @kishore kingmaker - For me the result is the same - the `0` axis grid line is empty in places where there are columns. Could you point out the difference? This is the result from jsfiddle: https://imgur.com/a/fGusPwY

Comment: see in code pen there is no space for columns which has 0 value

Comment: Ok, sorry for the misunderstanding - I thought you wanted to achieve the opposite result. Please try to increase `gridZIndex` for `yAxis`. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/45u2entx/

Comment: yup that works sup thanks a lot for your patience and effort

Comment: have a small problem on that when I give zindex: 4 for xaxis it also applied on all lines

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the grid line overlapps the bar when we add z-index

Comment: You can set the `zIndex` property only if there is one grid line. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/abx6vy9g/